How can I properly scrape the VISA Currency page when there's a Shadow-Root layer above the input fields?
I've been trying to automatically populate the VISA currency calculator page to calculate the exchange rate. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble accessing the fields because it seems there's a Shadow-Root layer above them.
I'm stuck. Can anyone help me with this? I'm using C# and have already tried Selenium and PuppeteerSharp. I haven't encountered any issues on other sites.
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
        options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");

        using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(options))
        {
   
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.visa.co.uk/support/consumer/travel-support/exchange-rate-calculator.html");

          
            string shadowRootId = (string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.querySelector('dm-calculator').shadowRoot.querySelector('*').id");

            // ID des Shadow-Root-Elements ausgeben (optional)
            Console.WriteLine($"Shadow Root ID: {shadowRootId}");

            // Eingabe des Transaktionswertes
 

            // Eingabe der Währung für "From"
           

            // Eingabe der Währung für "To"
            List<string> targetCurrencies = new List<string>
            {
                "AFN", "ALL", "DZD", "AOA", "ARS", "AMD", "AWG", "AUD", "AZN", "BSD",
                "BHD", "BDT", "BBD", "BYN", "BZD", "BMD", "BTN", "BOB", "BAM", "BWP",
                "BRL", "BND", "BGN", "BIF", "KHR", "CAD", "CVE", "KYD", "XOF", "XAF",
                "XPF", "CLP", "CNY", "COP", "KMF", "CDF", "CRC", "CUP", "CZK", "DKK",
                "DJF", "DOP", "XCD", "EGP", "SVC", "ETB", "EUR", "FKP", "FJD", "GMD",
                "GEL", "GHS", "GIP", "GBP", "GTQ", "GNF", "GYD", "HTG", "HNL", "HKD",
                "HUF", "ISK", "INR", "IDR", "IQD", "ILS", "JMD", "JPY", "JOD", "KZT",
                "KES", "KWD", "KGS", "LAK", "LBP", "LSL", "LRD", "LYD", "MOP", "MKD",
                "MGA", "MWK", "MYR", "MVR", "MRU", "MUR", "MXN", "MDL", "MNT", "MAD",
                "MZN", "MMK", "NAD", "NPR", "ANG", "NZD", "NIO", "NGN", "NOK", "OMR",
                "PKR", "PAB", "PGK", "PYG", "PEN", "PHP", "PLN", "QAR", "RON", "RUB",
                "RWF", "SHP", "WST", "STN", "SAR", "RSD", "SCR", "SLE", "SGD", "SBD",
                "SOS", "ZAR", "KRW", "SSP", "LKR", "SDG", "SRD", "SZL", "SEK", "CHF",
                "TWD", "TJS", "TZS", "THB", "TOP", "TTD", "TND", "TRY", "TMT", "UGX",
                "UAH", "AED", "USD", "UYU", "UZS", "VUV", "VES", "VND", "YER", "ZMW",
                "ZWL"
            };

            foreach (string currency in targetCurrencies)
            {



            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}



If you want to get currency data there must surely be plenty of APIs you can use, with a lot less hassle. Why take this scraping approach?

Here's a simple example of how to get access to the shadow-root.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
ISearchContext shadow_root = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("dm-calculator"))).GetShadowRoot();
shadow_root.FindElement(By.Id("input_amount_paid")).SendKeys("1.00");

This accesses the shadow-root and sets the "Amount you paid" field to "1.00". That should be enough to get you started.
